# jquery form validation with username availibility check

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am working on form validation using jQuery (jquery.validate.js). I need to check if a username is available, but I just couldn't figure it out how to do it. Please help.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="username" class="required checkAvailability" />
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $.validator.addMethod("checkAvailability", function(username) {
    var isSuccess = false;
    $.ajax({ url: "/checkAvailibility",
      data: "username=" + username,
      async: false,
      success: function(available) {
        if (available == "TRUE")
            isSuccess = true;
        return $("message", returnData).text() == "Username available";
      }
    });
  }, "Username not available");

  $("#formID").validate();

});
```

The server-side program returns a string which is either "TRUE" or "FALSE" (returned by the "returnData" variable).

My question:
How can I return both the message and the checking result to validate() so that the message may show up beside the field and the form will not be submitted if the username is not available?

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod#namemethodmessage

Answer (score 0):

Can you restructure your code a little? Something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $validUsername = false;

  $("input.checkAvailability").keyup(function(){

    $.ajax({ url: "/checkAvailibility",
      data: "username=" + $(this).val(),
      success: function(available) {
        if (available == "TRUE"){
            $validUsername = true;
            $("message", returnData).text("Username available");
        }
        else{
            // Do something
        }
      }
    });

  }); 

  $.validator.addMethod("checkAvailability", function(username) {
    return $validUsername;
  }, "Username not available");

  $("#formID").validate();

});
```

Comment: Thanks, but no matter what my server-side program returns, "Username not available" always shows up. What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The standard and most simple way to check a form field on the server is to use the 'remote' method.  From your server side method just return the text 'true' or 'false', not returnData=true or anything else.

Javascript should be this

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $('form').validate({
        rules: { username: 
            {
            remote: '/checkAvailibility'
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented this by using codeigniter. May this helps u.

Controller function:

```
  function checkUserName()
{
    $user_name=$_GET['user_name'];
    if(isset($user_name))
    {
        $arr=$this->home_model->checkUserName($user_name);
        $cnt=count($arr);
        if($cnt > 0)
            echo json_encode(false);
        else
            echo json_encode(true);
    }
}
```

Model Function:

```
function checkUserName($user_name)
{
    $this->db->select('a.id');
    $this->db->like('a.user_name',$user_name,'none');
    return $this->db->get('accounts a')->result();
    $this->db->get('accounts a')->result();
    echo $this->db->last_query();
    die;
}
```

HTML and JS:

```
<input type="text" name="user_name" placeholder="User name" id="user_name" class="form-control" value="">
```

JS:

```
$('#signup').validate(
{
    rules: 
    {
        user_name: 
        {
               //required: true,
        remote: baseUrl+'home/checkUserName'
        }
    }

    //Your Code here.......
}
```